# forward declaration of std::ostream

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

The files are organized as following:

```
//MyClass.h
#pragma once
namespace std {
    class ostream;
};
class MyClass
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClass& obj);
};
```

```
//MyClass.cpp
#include<iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClass& obj)
{
    o << obj.a << std::endl;
    return o;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include"MyClass.h"
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    std::cout << obj;
}
```

It failed compiling with errors on overloading `operator<<`:

> Error C2371 'std::ostream': redefinition; different basic types

What's the issue here and how to correct it?

Comment: `std::ostream` is not a class, it is an alias to a specialization of a template class. You can include `<iostream>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Here is the error info :
Error C2371 'std::ostream': redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @dalfaB I know I can remove the error by including <iostream> in the MyClass.h file. But I don't know why I cannot using forward declaration here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other people noted, `ostream` is not a class but an alias to a template instantiation, basically `ostream = basic_ostream<char>`. This is an implementation detail of the standard library; it's there because it needs to support also `wostream` (which is `basic_ostream<wchar_t>`) and possibly other stream types. But other implementations may do it differently (using e.g. source code generation) or very differently (distributing pre-compiled modules). You should not depend on any particular implementation.

---

You should not declare anything inside the `std` namespace (except stuff which the C++ Standard explicitly permits). To forward-declare `ostream` and such, use [`#include <iosfwd>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) in your header file.

Alternatively, just do `#include <iostream>` instead of forward declaration — less technical details to remember vs slightly slower compilation — do your own judgment on what is better.

Comment: Is <iosfwd> a file specially made for forward declaration of std stuff?

Comment: @SZYoo Specifically it's for the I/O part of the standard library. But these days compilers are fast. I would just include what you need and not use forward declarations for the standard library.

Comment: @john I just want to make the things behind clearer. I don't know why the way I do it is not allowed.

Comment: Here, it's not allowed because `std::ostream` **is not a class**, so your code is not valid (two different `std::ostream` types are detected). For other items in std library it's not allowed for similar reasons.

Comment: @dalfaB do you mean that it is an aliasing name not being a class? Then, do C/C++ not permit forward declaration of aliasing names?

Comment: An alias is a declaration, you can redo the same alias if you want. But `std::ostream` is the same as `std::basic_ostream<char>` but `class ostream` does not exists.